# Get index of match from tr1::regex_search

Tags: c++, regex, tr1

How can I get the index of the match when using `std::tr1::regex_search`?

```
// sequence of string sub-matches
std::tr1::smatch result;

if (!std::tr1::regex_search(text, result, pattern))
    return false;
```

I can get only the string from the `std::tr1::smatch result` variable, but not the index of the match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had missed it because I searched for an `index` method, but it's right there as a method - `std::tr1::smatch::position()` will give the index of the match.

Comment: Well, that didn't escalate at all.

Comment: I found the method thanks to this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/234277/492336. It was about Boost, but the regex class seems to be identical in tr1. So StackOverflow still helped a lot.